# transparent background of GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

i wrote a code using GridLayou, however i cant manage to delete the grey background and use the img i plugged as a background, and the picture demonstrate the problem:

[image]

Can someone please help?

this is the code

```
public class mainClass {


private static  JButton start;
static BackgroundPanel bp = null;
static JFrame mainf = null;
static int R;
final static boolean shouldFill = true;

// group turns boolean
boolean redTurn = false;
boolean blueTurn = false;
boolean greenTurn = false;
boolean yellowTurn = false;

// boards
static ImageIcon gameBoard;
static ImageIcon blueBoard;
static ImageIcon qBoard;

 // dice
static JButton dice_1 = null;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     mainf = new JFrame ("سين جيم");


    // background
    BufferedImage mFrame = ImageIO.read(new File("B1.png"));
    bp = new BackgroundPanel(mFrame);
    mainf.add(bp);
    bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  //  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


    // Hi string 
    JLabel hi = new JLabel ("أهلا وسهلا بكم في لعبة الليدو");
    Font fs = hi.getFont();
    hi.setFont(fs.deriveFont(50f));


    bp.add(hi);

    // empty

    // button 
    start = new JButton ( "لنبدأاللعب");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


    c.ipady = 20;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
    bp.add(start, c);



    // Action Listener
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

              // starting the game area 

              // emptying all
              bp.removeAll();
              bp.revalidate();
              bp.repaint();
              BufferedImage mFrame2= null;
            try {
                // changing background
                mFrame2 = ImageIO.read(new File("B2.png"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // setting new background
              bp = new BackgroundPanel(mFrame2);
              bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

              GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
              // adding gameBoard 
              gameBoard = new ImageIcon("gameBoard.png");
              JLabel gameBoard_1 = new JLabel(gameBoard);
              bp.add(gameBoard_1);

            // adding blueBoard 
              blueBoard = new ImageIcon("blueBoard.png");
              JLabel blueBoard_1 = new JLabel(blueBoard);
              bp.add(blueBoard_1);


              GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(4,4); // rows | , cols-                
              blueBoard_1.setLayout(experimentLayout);

              // gameName panel
              JPanel gameName = new JPanel();
              gameName.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

              JLabel Ledu= new JLabel ("لعبة اللدو");
              Font font3 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30);
              Ledu.setFont(font3);
              Ledu.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

              gameName.add(Ledu);

              // teamPanel
              JPanel teamName = new JPanel();
              teamName.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));  

              JLabel blue= new JLabel ("الفريق الأرزق");
              Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
              blue.setFont(font2);
              blue.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
              JLabel red= new JLabel ("الفريق الأحمر");
              red.setFont(font2);
              red.setForeground(Color.RED);      
              JLabel yellow= new JLabel ("الفريق الأصفر");
              yellow.setFont(font2);
              yellow.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);     
              JLabel green= new JLabel ("الفريق الأخضر");
              green.setFont(font2);
              green.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
              // team panel
              teamName.add(blue);
              teamName.add(red);
              teamName.add(yellow);
              teamName.add(green);

              // adding question
              JPanel question = new JPanel();
              question.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
              ImageIcon q = new ImageIcon("Q.png");
              JLabel q_1 = new JLabel(q);
              // adding Question panel
              question.add(q_1);

              // dicePanel

              final JPanel dicePanel = new JPanel();
              dicePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,0));  
              ImageIcon dice = new ImageIcon("dice.png");
              dice_1 = new JButton(dice);

              // adding dice panel
              dicePanel.add(dice_1);
              dice_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                      dicePanel.remove(dice_1);
                      dicePanel.revalidate();
                      dicePanel.repaint();
                      ImageIcon dice = new ImageIcon("dice.gif");
                    dice_1 = new JButton(dice);
                  dicePanel.add(dice_1);

                 // random number 
                 Random r = new Random();
                 R = r.nextInt(10) + 2;
                 System.out.println(R);

                  }
              });




              // Centeralizing Ledu
              Ledu.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              gameName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
              blue.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              red.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              yellow.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              green.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              teamName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


              // no backgrounf color
              Ledu.setOpaque( false );
              gameName.setOpaque( false );
              blue.setOpaque( false );
              red.setOpaque( false );
              yellow.setOpaque( false );
              green.setOpaque( false );
              teamName.setOpaque( false );
              question.setOpaque( false );
              dicePanel.setOpaque( false );

              // final add 
              blueBoard_1.add(gameName, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
              blueBoard_1.add(teamName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              blueBoard_1.add(question, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
              blueBoard_1.add(dicePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

              /*
              // add dice
               ImageIcon dice = new ImageIcon("dice.png");
               dice_1 = new JButton(dice);
               dice_1.setSize(100, 70);
               bp.add(dice_1);

               // changin to moving dice
              dice_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                      bp.remove(dice_1);
                      bp.revalidate();
                      bp.repaint();
                      ImageIcon dice = new ImageIcon("dice.gif");
                    dice_1 = new JButton(dice);
                    dice_1.setSize(100, 70);
                   bp.add(dice_1);

                 // random number 
                 Random r = new Random();
                 int R = r.nextInt(10) + 2;
                 System.out.println(R);

                  }
              });

              */


                mainf.setContentPane(bp);




          };}); // end of start actionListener

                mainf.pack();
                mainf.setVisible(true);

};

    // dice class

}
```

Comment: added the code now :)

Comment: @Neyon, `any idea how to adjust the size of the column so i can view the img i want it to view ?` What column? What image? Your question was about displaying labels on a blue background. I have no idea what you are asking now.

Comment: yes this is a different question 
if u give a look to this picture : http://puu.sh/k4AoT/d21707be38.png u can tell that the img bellow ( http://puu.sh/k4E0s/4c1cf9e53b.png ) is incomplete, any idea how to adjust that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JPanel is opaque by default so you see a grey background.

You need to use:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

if you add a panel to your component containing the background image.

By the way you should NOT be using static variables. Look at the examples from the Swing tutorial for a better way to create your frames. That is create a class to represent your game. This would be a JPanel. Then you define all the variables you need for you game in this class. Then you simple add the panel to the frame. You should NOT be createing components in the main() method.

Comment: thanks i fixed it now, any idea how to adjust the size of the column so i can view the img i want it to view ? http://puu.sh/k4AoT/d21707be38.png